Arithmetic Mean of a Harmonic Function over concentric circles
I'm going through Ahlfors Complex Analysis.  I'm trying to understand theorem 20 in the book.  Basically, given that in spherical coordinates the conjugate differential is $^*du=r(\partial u/\partial r)d\theta$.  Define $u_1=\log r$ and $u_2=u$ harmonic in $|z|<\rho$.  By Cauchy's theorem we have
$$\int_{\gamma}u_1\;^*du_2-u_2\;^*du_1=0$$
which allows us to conclude that
$$\int_{|z|=r}ud\theta-\log r\int_{|z|=r}r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}d\theta$$
is constant.  Likewise,
$$\int_{|z|=r}r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}d\theta$$
is constant if $u$ is harmonic in an annulus, and zero if $u$ is harmonic in the whole disc.  He hen says that the arithmetic mean of a harmonic function over concentric circles $|z|=r$ is a linear function of $\log r$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|z|=r}ud\theta=\alpha\log r+\beta$$
if $u$ is harmonic in a disc, $\alpha=0$ and the arithmetic mean is constant.
What I don't understand is what he says next.  He says that if $u$ is harmonic in a disc, "$\beta=u(0)$ by continuity.  What I'm not sure is what this means.  My understanding is that $u(0)$ is the value of $u$ at $r=0$.  The reason that $\beta=u(0)$ is because the concentric circles shrink continuously, and the point $r=0$ is a limit point of this "sequence" $\beta=u(0)$.  However, I'm not super convinced this is true, since every point in a continuous sequence is a limit point, so there wouldn't be a reason to favour $r=0$ over any other $r$ value.  Is he talking about the arithmetic mean as a function of $r$ being continuous?
